# Algorithm for finding "fact families"

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, education

My friend's 3rd grader encountered the following question regarding "fact families" on her math homework:

[image: fact families]

I was in 3rd grade sometime in the 1980s, so I don't believe I ever encountered this term before.  Her mother was having some trouble interpreting the question, so after a little research I wrote a short Python script to generate these "fact families":

```
vars = [(i,j) for i in xrange(2,100) for j in xrange (2,100) if j >= i and i*j < 100]

output = []

for i,j in vars:
    product = i*j
    digits = [i,j,product]
    seen = []

    for digit in str(i) + str(j) + str(product):
        if digit not in seen:
            seen.append(digit)

    if len(seen) == 3:
       output.append(digits)

print output
print len(output)
```

With the result:

[[2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 8], [2, 6, 12], [2, 10, 20], [2, 12, 24], [2, 20, 40], [2, 21, 42], [2, 24, 48], [2, 25, 50], [2, 26, 52], [2, 33, 66], [2, 42, 84], [2, 44, 88], [3, 5, 15], [3, 10, 30], [3, 13, 39], [3, 22, 66], [3, 30, 90], [3, 31, 93], [4, 4, 16], [4, 6, 24], [4, 10, 40], [4, 16, 64], [4, 22, 88], [5, 7, 35], [5, 9, 45], [5, 10, 50], [5, 15, 75], [5, 19, 95], [6, 8, 48], [6, 10, 60], [6, 16, 96], [7, 7, 49], [7, 10, 70], [8, 8, 64], [8, 10, 80], [9, 9, 81], [9, 10, 90]]

38

I think the purpose of this exercise is to allow the student to practice their times tables or...something.  I don't know that I agree with this type of mathematics education, but as soliciting responses on such an issue would be primarily opinion-based I guess I will refrain from asking about that directly.

The algorithm in the code searches for the families with three different digits probably the same way a 3rd grader would: scanning the numbers in all combinations of factors and products and noting the sets where only three have appeared, i.e. brute force.  Is there any more clever (computationally efficient) way to generate these sets?

Comment: What a bizarre concept. There are lots of facts in math that can be reasonably be called "families" as collections of related facts (for example any formula with a variable in it, i.e. $a(b+c)=ab+ac$), but this is one of the few cases where that certainly *does not* apply, and $2\times3=6$ is as far as I can tell *exactly one* "fact" about numbers. So calling it a "fact family" is...

Comment: does $1 \times 23 = 23$ count?

Comment: @Mario: It appears from a bit of searching on the web that a ‘fact family’ is a set of four related arithmetic statements. Specifically, an addition and subtraction fact family is a set

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&a+b=c\\
&b+a=c\\
&c-a=b\\
&c-b=a\;,
\end{align*}\right.$$

and a multiplication and division fact family is a set

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&a\times b=c\\
&b\times a=c\\
&c\div a=b\\
&c\div b=a\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$ $2\times 3=6$ is simply a representative of its family, not the whole family.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Haha, so I guess $0\times 6=0$ isn't in a fact family then...

Comment: From the text I learn: A "multiplication fact" is one member of a "fact family" (and there may be several multiplication facts in a fact family) and $2\times 3=6$ **is** a  fact family. Also, fact families have several "dividends". - This is totally weird. My best bet would be that a fact family is a collection of related facts, such as $a\cdot b=c$, $b\cdot a=c$, $c:a=b$, and $c:b=a$. That interpretation matches *some* of the information readable from the problem statement, but it clearly contradicts others.

Comment: @Mario: Maybe a single-parent family? :-)

Comment: @Joffan She told me after she consulted with the child's teacher that families including "1" as a factor should be excluded; originally the program included them.  I do not understand why.  Nobody else seems to be able to agree either: http://www.blurtit.com/2259050/the-fact-families-2x36-and-2x1020-contain-exactly-3-different-digits-how-many-other-fact

Comment: Note that computational efficiency is difficult to assess in this case since the problem is bounded ($n=100$), so there is no asymptotic to look at. The most efficient approach is just to print out the 36-some solutions (stored directly in the code), and the question trivializes. And if you let $n\to\infty$, the character of the problem seems to change, since most numbers will have more than three distinct digits.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Well, I'm assuming that it's not possible to store the sets.  In terms of computationl efficiency, as the algorithm is brute force, I'm also assuming that while we don't know the specific O of this there is probably no _worse_ algorithm for generating the sets other than say the random "bogo sort" approach

Comment: @MarioCarneiro if a better algorithm cannot be found it might also be an interesting problem to see if a bound on the number of sets with exactly _k_ digits under _n_ could be determined

Comment: @Bitrex My point is that any algorithm to solve this, assuming it always completes, has complexity $O(1)$, since there is exactly one problem to solve so the program will do the same thing each time. For a probabilistic algorithm, it may run shorter sometimes and longer other times, but it will have some mean and so it will still have expected run time $O(1)$.

Comment: @Bitrex I will agree that analyzing the answer to the question as a function of $n$ ($n=100$ here) would make an interesting answer.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Ok, I understand what you mean.